# Multiple parameters of different types sqlite3 python

Tags: python, parameters, sqlite, sql-update, where-clause

I can't seem to figure out how to parameterize multiple different formats (both real and string in the same query

```
conn = sqlite3.connect(dbfile)
c = conn.cursor()

def update_data(text,var2):
    c.execute("UPDATE T SET T12M = ? WHERE date = ?", (var2, text))
    conn.commit()
```

It works if I hard code what I want but I can't seem to get the variable number/text to work. For ex this works but I want to pass in variable numbers/strings:
UPDATE T SET T12M = 10 WHERE date = '9/28/2015';

Comment: What do you mean when you say it doesn't work?

Comment: Are you confident that that date is represented in the table?

Comment: I mean that it does not update the value in the T12M column at all. Yes If I type UPDATE T SET T12M = 10 WHERE date = '9/28/2015' It works.

Comment: I am testing it with update_data('9/28/2015',20)

Comment: You seem to have the parameters in opposite orders, ie, date first in the call but date second in the execute/update.

Comment: yes that is intentional. I want the second ? to be the date and the first ? to be the var2

Comment: Have I passed my own confusion on to you yet? :) Anyway, when all else fails, read the manual, which says that dates must be in the format YYYY-MM-DD. Could that be it? (See https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html.)

Comment: I don't see why that would be it. It's text in sqlite. It's irrelevant what the actual text is.

Answer (score -2):

Try with the curly braces and .format() method:

```
c.execute("UPDATE T SET T12M = {} WHERE date = {}".format(var2, text))
```